# LINQ query involving generics not working

Tags: linq

I don't see what I'm doing wrong with the LINQ query below.

I'm building a generic type:

```
public class MyClass<TKey, TValue> : IList<TValue> { ... }
```

Within this class I declare a nested private type:

```
private class Pair {
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public Pair() {
        Key = default( TKey );
        Value = default( TValue );
    }
}
```

So far so good.  Now, in `MyClass` I have a method which has an array of `TKey` objects.  I want to use LINQ to extract a page of `TKey` objects and create a smaller array of `Pair` objects.  Here's the query I've built:

```
TKey[] Keys = ...;
IQueryable<Pair> query = from key in Keys
                         select new Pair { Key = key, Value = default( TValue ) };
```

When I compile the program, I get the following error on the line with the select in it:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyNameSpace.MyClass<TKey,TValue>.Pair>'
to  'System.Linq.IQueryable<VirtualLoadApp.MyClass<TKey,TValue>.Pair>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Tony

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: The text of the error message is at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
            var q = from key in Keys
                    select (new Pair { Key = key, Value = default(TValue) });
            IQueryable<Pair> query = q.AsQueryable<Pair>();
```